# Increasing Performance on this SQL w/Large Data

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm curious if this is just a restraint on the resources or Reporting Vertica Instance has and if there are ways to increase efficiency in data joins like this.

Attached SQL below times out constantly if running on a local machine as queries only have a certain timespan to run unless I run it on the server instance. Timeout generally happens between 20 -> 30 minutes.

Basically what I am wondering if there are better ways to pivot data on Open/End Dates when you have large amounts of data. The base table being 56M records in this instance, but could be greater for other use cases.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
DATE,
MEMBER_ID

FROM
(SELECT 
DATE 
FROM ANALYTICS.DATE   //Date Mapping Table Scaffolding Data
) PD
INNER JOIN

(SELECT 
MEMBER_ID, 
DATE(DATE) AS ACTIVE_DATE , 
DATE(TIMESTAMPADD('DAY',30,DATE)) AS INACTIVE_DATE 
FROM  
ANALYTICS.DATA //Base  Table has 56M Distinct Records
WHERE 
YEAR(DATE(TIMESTAMPADD('DAY',30,DATE)))>=YEAR(DATE(TIMESTAMPADD('YEAR',-1,NOW())))   //Limiting Data to relevant Period
) AC ON PD.DATE BETWEEN AC.ACTIVE_DATE AND AC.INACTIVE_DATE //Scaffolding Data
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  It is not clear to me at all what is being "pivoted".

Comment: Only got experience with SQL Server and don't know your syntax, but at a guess: the `WHERE` filter should really be a proper interval and filtering directly on `DATE` with no functions, something like `DATE > beginning_of_month_function(TIMESTAMPADD('YEAR',-1,NOW()))`. Also the join is on a function `ACTIVE_DATE`, you are better off joining with an interval period `PD.DATE + 1 BETWEEN AC.DATE AND AC.INACTIVE_DATE`. Then you have indexing on those date columns

Comment: @Charlieface I have to say, sometimes its the little things that I just overlook for expediency, I need to get in a better habit forgoing date functions for interval function. That helped, I had the DW team build additional projections which also improved performance.

Comment: Add the output of: `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','analytics.date',FALSE);` and `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','analytics.data',FALSE);`  to your question. The answer to your question depends on the data types used, the projections used: ordering, segmenting, and encoding